# Zip high volume of folders & files

Tags: powershell, backup, archive

I've a huge problem with backup of one share which contain a huge volume (10 000 000 +) small files. As far as I know total MegaBytes of those files are not so big, but the biggest problem is number of files.

First things first:
- share is more or less "regular" so there is a root directory which contain lets say 30 directories. All of those 1st level directories contain subfolder with date in format: yyMMdd.

I've created some PowerShell script to zip those directories based on date in their names, so, right now, I'm runing backup only on .zip files, but...

I've observed that script run time is everyday increasing (since this script still need to check all of folders anyway). And count of folders are increasing every day

My question is:
Is there any - let's say - marker to use it in this way: 
- when script run and add directory to the archive mark today folders as "already archived", to skip those already archived folders in next script run.

That will give me everyday more or less the same time of script runtime, since it will be "check & archive" more or less the same ammount of directories which are not archived already.

Can anyone put some advice? Any idea? I'm running back of options right now.

Script is not very sophitsticated:

```
$zip = "C:\apps\7-zip\7z.exe"
$days_behind = -1
$folder_data = (Get-Date).AddDays($days_behind).ToString("yyMMdd")
$archive = "X:\SHARE_ARCH\Archive_$folder_data.zip"
$to_zip = (gci X:\SHARE_ROOT -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ?{$_.Name -contains ($folder_data)}).FullName
$options = "a", "-tzip", "-y", $archive, $to_zip;
$zip $options;
```

I think that most problematic is this line:

**$to_zip = (gci X:\SHARE_ROOT -Recurse | ?{ $*.PSIsContainer } | ?{$*.Name -contains ($folder_data)}).FullName**

Comment: what does your script look like and how do you check the folders and what do you check for? show us the code

Comment: Added to orginal post

Comment: What version of powershell are you running?

Comment: Thank you all, I've redesigned "search query", and now it works like I want.

Comment: Did you try @TheMadTechnician's or my solution(and if so, which one was faster)?

Comment: Nope, I've redesign it and starting using SQL, for history etc...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you have PSv3 or higher you can remove the `$_.PSIsContainer -and` and instead add `-Directory` to the GCI command which should help speed it up by filtering at the provider level instead of afterwards.

This will stop it from recursing everything and will just pull all the folders in the root folder, and check to see if they have a subfolder with the desired name on it. That should speed things up considerably.

```
$zip = "C:\apps\7-zip\7z.exe"
$days_behind = -1
$folder_data = (Get-Date).AddDays($days_behind).ToString("yyMMdd")
$archive = "X:\SHARE_ARCH\Archive_$folder_data.zip"
$to_zip = gci X:\SHARE_ROOT | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -and (test-path "$_\$folder_data")} | Select -Expand FullName
$options = "a", "-tzip", "-y", $archive, $to_zip
& $zip $options
```

I also removed the parenthesis and used a `Select -expand` command instead. I don't know that it will really change the speed any, but it's cleaner in general.

Answer (score 0):

This will eliminate second *where* statement which should speed things up:

```
$to_zip = (gci X:\SHARE_ROOT -Recurse -Include ("*" + $folder_data + "*") |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
```

As per @TheMadTechnician, if you have PS3+ you can use *-Directory* switch with *gci* to further speed things up. A slightly leftfield approach is to use the old command prompt to obtain list of directories and process them in Powershell - **much faster!** Try this:

```
$to_zip = (cmd /c "dir X:\SHARE_ROOT /A:D /S /B | findstr /i $folder_data") -split "`n"
```

Let me know how you get on.